# Где в wildfly 8.2.1 взять спецификацию Java EE

Tags: java, build, wildfly

Я сконфигурировал wildfly в eclipse. У меня есть старые проекты, которые раньше деплоились под glassfish, теперь я решил полностью перейти на wildfly. Подскажите откуда взять соответствующие библиотеки для EE спецификации???

Comment: Они уже есть в Wildfly, а вот задача по переходу с glassfish на WildFly может быть нетривиальной задачей

Comment: Модули API можно взять хоть откуда. Они же нужны только для компиляции. Где они в сервере и не важно. А так всё раскидано по папкам внутри папки winldfly\modules